# How to configure .htaccess file for two different websites routing in my shared hosting server

Tags: php, reactjs, .htaccess, url-routing

I am using host gator shared hosting and I have already a php app serving on a different domain.
Now I hosted another domain with my react app.

Hosting works fine but when I reload on a specific url, I get 500 error.
I found the answer for this is, react router is doing routing so when reload on specific url, it do not find the file for that url. makes sense.

original `.htaccess` in `public_html` folder

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>    
    # Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With, x-api-key"
</IfModule>
# Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>


# Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
# Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"
# Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"


# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php82” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php82___lsphp .php .php8 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Now I am trying to add my own routing rules for react app which I found in a  blog

added these in `IfModule` block.`RewriteCond` rules already exist so I did not duplicated that

```
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

and after debugging I realized the order matters
now the file looks like this

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>    
    # Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With, x-api-key"
</IfModule>
# Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    
#FOR REACT
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
#

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#FOR REACT
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
    # RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>


# Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
# Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"
# Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"


# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php82” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php82___lsphp .php .php8 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

now the issue is with the last two rules in the block which are:

```
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
# RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

if I use both, my both sites give 404
if I use index.html, react works perfectly, if I use index.php, the php website works correctly

how can I use both without any routing problem?

[edit] this is document root path where react files are

[image]

`.htaccess` is in `~/public_html` folder

Comment: How are you trying to reach the react app, did you put it into its own folder below the domain root or something?

Comment: I am puting react files in document root folder for this website as told by host gator,
I have addedd a screeshot of that root path @CBroe

Comment: Point of my question was, do you intend to _access_ your react app in a folder below the domain? So `example.com/my-react-app/` - everything below that path will be content served by your react app, everything "outside" it content from the old, existing website?

Comment: no I have 2 different domains
I want react app to be served on for example `domain1.com/`
I want the other app to be served on `domain2.com/` as it is working already @CBroe

Comment: I am already achiving this by putting react build files in `~/public_html/webiste_8e4ae73`
the pervious website is  similarly in another folder which is `~/public_html/website_95c4e9ea` @CBroe

Comment: I just want to set rule `RewriteRule . /index.html [L]` in .htaccess for react app which is clashing with already existing rule for other webiste `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]` @CBroe

Comment: Then you should probably move the .htaccess you currently have in the public_html folder, into the folder of the actual website? Not sure _how_ the two domains get routed into the respective folders in your setup, but it doesn't seem to be due to that .htaccess content you have shown. (Also, not sure what it would currently be targeting, when it redirects to index.php _in_ the public_html folder?)